# Setting a foreign key association based on route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Here is my code as it sits now...

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :registrations

class Registration < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :article

#app/views/articles/show.html.erb
    <%= link_to 'Register', new_registration_path({:article_id => @article}) %>

#app/views/registrations/_form.html.erb
  <%= f.hidden_field :article_id %>

#app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb
 def new
    @registration = Registration.new
    @registration.article = Article.find params[:article_id]
```

..and this works just peachy. However, I would like to get rid of the code in app/views/articles/show.html.erb and do this with a route...

```
    <%= link_to 'Register', new_article_registration_path(@article) %>
```

...and I would also like to get rid of hte hidden_field that I am using in the registrations view. I know I need to add a build method to my controller, but I am not sure if I should add this to the article or registration controller. Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In your `routes.rb` you can make nested resources:

```
resources :articles do
  resources :registrations
end
```

Then you can make your links using the "magic" of the [polymorphic_url](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/PolymorphicRoutes.html#method-i-polymorphic_url) method in your `link_to` helper:

```
<%= link_to 'Register', [:new, @article, :registration] %>
```

Comment: Thanx jdoe..is <%= link_to 'Register', [:new, @article, :registration] %> not the same as     <%= link_to 'Register', new_article_registration_path(@article) %>? I have the same code in my routes.rb file. But I am not getting article_id as a parameter when I save a registration.

Comment: @Lumbee Yes, it's basically the same, but more concise. This is strange that your code didn't work. Check if you didn't lose the trailing `s` in `resources` for your `:articles`.

Comment: No, my routes are good. I am thinking I need something like `@article = Article.find params[:article_id]` or `@registration = @article.registrations.build ` in my registrations controller.